# How to remove whitespace added by Liquid's `{% include ... %}`

Tags: liquid

I'm using Liquid `{% include ... %}` inline to insert markup on my page. Doing so is causing whitespace to be added immediately after the include, and I can't remove it. I've attached screenshots of the output and markup for reference.

**Markup**

[image]

**Output**

[image]
[image]

**span.html**

```
<span>{{ include.content }}</span>
```

**anchor.html**

```
<a>{{ include.content }}</a>
```

Neither of the `{% include ... %}` files contain any white space before or after. I've tried using `{%- -%}` on the include itself and `{{- -}}` in the include files, but to no avail.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the culprit was my text editor, ATOM. There's a package installed and enabled by default called [whitespace](https://github.com/atom/whitespace). The description for the package is:

```
Strips trailing whitespace and adds a trailing newline when an editor is saved.
```

I've disabled the package, resaved my includes and everything is now working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that there are no line breaks in your include. I.e. do not have an empty line at the end of `span.html`. Any line breaks in your include become line breaks in the output, which browsers render as a white space.

If you must have line breaks in the include for readability (e.g. if you're doing Liquid looping), you can capture its contents and then strip newlines from the result with a filter, like this:

```
{% capture span %}
<span>
    {{ include.content }}
</span>
{% endcapture %}{{ span | strip_newlines }}
```

Again, there must not be a blank line at the end of that include.